# videos are not responsive in devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build responsive video that changed on scrolling. It works properly in browser but it not shown to devices. my code is below..

```
<html>..<article data-l-nougat class="nougat">
    <video id="eleVideo" class="videos" autoplay loop style="display:block;">
        <source src="vid/01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video id="eleVideo2" class="videos" autoplay loop style="display:none;">
        <source src="vid/02.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video id="eleVideo3" class="videos" autoplay loop style="display:none;">
        <source src="vid/03.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

my css is as follows:

```
.videos {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
}
```

and in all browser it works properly but not worked in devices.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to search before asking question.

You can find CSS trick here: https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Answer (score 0):

Either you remove **position:fixed** from your **.videos** class or update that as following:

```
.videos {
width:100%;
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
right:0;
```

}

Please check attached code snippet.

```css
.videos {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 right:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video  controls autoplay loop class="videos" style="display:block;">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<p>
Video courtesy of
<a href="http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```